# Assist me in finding errors in PHP File Upload

Tags: php, file-upload

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload3.php" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="1000000" />
            Choose a file to upload: <input name="uploaded_file" type="file" />
            <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
        </form>
```

> The php code was working earlier but suddenly it stopped working, maybe due to some changes i made unknowingly

```
<?php 
      $uploaddir = "Uploads/";
      $uploadfile = $uploaddir.basename($_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);

echo "<pre style=font-size:20px>";
     if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile ))
     {
         echo "<b>File is valid,and was successfully uploaded !!!</b>.\n";
     }
     else
     {
         echo "<b>File upload Failed !!!</b>.\n";
     }
 ?>
```

The error is:

> Notice: Undefined index: uploaded_file in C:\xampp\htdocs\Upload.php on line 6 File upload Failed

Line 6:

```
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile ))
```

Comment: Have you got any errors?

Comment: Yes , it says Notice: 

 Undefined index: uploaded_file in C:\xampp\htdocs\Upload.php on line 6

File upload Failed !!!.

Here is some more debugging:

Comment: LINE 6 is : 
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile ))

Comment: First of all create or select file and then try to upload? particularly in database.

Comment: Please put the relevant stuff in the question and do not distribute it across question and comments.

Comment: try to check `print_r($_FILES);` and check  any index `uploaded_file` is there or not?

Comment: This might be moot as it's probably not real code, but as it stands, this code looks like it might allow people to upload any file into a public facing directory with exactly the same name they originally used. This is incredibly dangerous from a security stand point.

Comment: So What should i Do now ?